# What should we do with this question about why software is complicated?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

So [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/118481/8311) hit HNQ and is attracting a lot of argument at the moment. Notwithstanding that my answer to it is netting me large amounts of reputation right now, I think it's safe to say that the question is borderline off-topic and is not representative of what this site considers a good on-topic question.

I think it would be more on-topic at Software Engineering Stack Exchange, insofar as it's a question about the practice of software rather than the theory. However, the softer side of CS does bleed into SE around the edges, so it's not *totally* off-topic at the moment. There's a kernel of a good question here; you just have to read past the slights against Linux and 2FA to get to it.

1. Should the question be pulled from HNQ?
2. Should the question be migrated to, say, Software Engineering?
3. Does the question need to be edited?

Comment: I agree it does seem borderline.  I made some edits to make it more concise.  Perhaps that will help a little.  Maybe other can help make it even more focused.

Comment: I think this question it strictly offtopic on this site and should be closed. It's not about computer science at all; if anything, it's about social sciences and/or philosophy behind/about use and evolution of technology.